# How to configure cache folder for SourceDiskCache?

Tags: imageresizer

I understand from the documentation that the SourceDiskCache folder cannot be configured using the XML configuration file and is only available "through code installation".  However I can't figure out how!

I need to configure a custom folder.  I have tried a few different things, with different results (both in Application_Start):

1. This doesn't throw an error, but uses the default folder (/cache)

   ```
   var sourceDiskCachePlugin = new SourceDiskCachePlugin {VirtualCacheDir = "~/App_Data/cache"};
   Config.Current.Plugins.GetOrInstall(sourceDiskCachePlugin);
   ```
2. This (and most other variations I have tried) throws the error "SourceDiskCache settings may not be adjusted after it is started."

   ```
   new SourceDiskCachePlugin().Install(Config.Current);
   Config.Current.Plugins.Get<SourceDiskCachePlugin>().VirtualCacheDir = "~/App_Data/cache";
   ```

How can I configure this?

Also, the documentation states that SourceDiskCache is in beta - is this still the case, and will XML configuration ever be available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the normal way to configure and install it:

`var plugin = new SourceDiskCachePlugin()
plugin.VirtualCacheDir = "~/App_Data/cache";
plugin.Install(Config.Current);`

If your code is running more than once, use `Config.Current.Plugins.GetOrInstall(plugin);` It's best if you only install the plugin during Application_Start.

However, approach #1 from your question should work equally well, as long as you've set the right NTFS permissions on App_Data.

Comment: I just tried this and I get the same behaviour as my attempt #1 - the "VirtualCacheDir" setting is ignored and the source images get cached in the /cache/sourceimages folder.

Comment: What do you have in Web.config?

Comment: `<resizer>  
<plugins>  
    <add name="S3Reader2" prefix="~/m" region="us-east-1" {snip} />  
    <add name="DiskCache" />  
    <add name="SourceDiskCache" />  
    <add name="Watermark" />  
    <add name="Presets" />  
</plugins>  
<diskcache dir="~/App_Data/cache"  autoClean="false" />  
<watermarks>  
    {snip}  
</watermarks>  
<presets onlyAllowPresets="false">  
    {snip}  
</presets>  
</resizer>`

Comment: Following up after 1 week.  Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: SourceDiskCache only allows one instance; I think you'll need to remove it from Web.config in order to actually install it in Application_Start.